# Usuário aparentemente "zoando"

Tags: debate, comportamento, novos-usuários

O usuário https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/22190/lol além de usar o nome como `LOL` (seria algo como "rindo alto") respondeu a uma pergunta de maneira estranha:

A unica resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/52436/3635 soa como uma tentativa de sarcasmo ou qualquer coisa assim:

> refazer 4245415445131313513
>
> wqewqewqewqewqewqewqewqeqwewqewqewqewqewqewqewq

Talvez alerta-lo (realmente acho que isso não vai ajudar neste caso expecifico) ajudaria?

Comment: Não tem mistério, é só sinalizar. De vez em quando aparece um troll órfão, basta não jogar ração que eles somem. :)

Comment: Hasta la vista, LOL.

Comment: usuário lol: I'll be back https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgLfOrVJJMg

Comment: Ver essa pergunta no [nosso Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT/status/572322124314095616) foi a melhor maneira de começar a semana :D

Comment: @PapaCharlie, "troll orfão", lol d+ pra isso, jejeje

Comment: @brasofilo não basta ser toll, tem que ser órfão, o cara atingiu *+1000* de XP... rsrs

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Esse tipo de coisa é bem frequente. É bom sempre sinalizar, como [sugeriu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2521/usu%c3%a1rio-aparentemente-zoando#comment8593_2521) o Papa Charlie. Na maioria dos casos, os usuários e publicações acabam removidos pelos moderadores.

Um fator a observar é se o usuário é registrado ou não. Usuários não registrados (essa identificação está no perfil dele, ao lado do username) não têm uma conta estável no site. Como a política do site é não exigir cadastro para postar, uma conta é criada *ad hoc* se a pessoa optar por não se cadastrar. A única ligação entre a conta e o usuário é algo gravado no computador utilizado (não sei se em cookie ou local storage), e de outro computador não há como usar a mesma conta. Resultado: a conta acaba perdida na maioria das vezes (ou mesclada por um gerente de comunidade com outra conta da mesma pessoa, caso haja).

Para ver se vale a pena tentar ajudar a pessoa, verifique o tipo de conta usado, e se o usuário tem outras postagens (de preferência úteis, ou que no mínimo façam algum sentido). E como ele está usando uma conta potencialmente efêmera, tenha em conta que as chances de comunicação com ele diminuem com o passar do tempo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas, realmente eu nunca tenho "sorte" de ver este tipo de usuário, realmente aqui é a primeira vez

Comment: Sorte mesmo. Já eu acabo vendo a maioria deles :)

Comment: Cara você realmente fica muito tempo online :) parabéns pelo trabalho de limpeza aqui no stackoverflow. Só tenho a agradecer, se raramente vemos um destes tipos de caras é graças a você e aos demais moderadores